# How to set isolation.level kafka camel component

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any form to set `isolation.level` in kafka endpoint configuration from `camel`?
I already try to set `isolation.level=read_commited` but I received one exception from configuration.

Comment: What version of Camel are you using? and What version of Kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to set isolation.level for Camel kafka consumer, have a look at KafkaConfiguration#createConsumerProperties method: `ConsumerKey.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG` is never set